# Connecting iMac to Air via Thunderbolt port 1 AND to an external SSD via TB port 2

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt, ethernet

I connected a MB Air to my iMac 5K via Thunderbolt 3.  I configured networking on bridge0 on the iMac to include TB port 1 and ethernet, then used the Apple cable to connect TB port 1 to my MBA.  That works fine.  The green 'connected' light is on in the Network settings page.

However to make it work, I had to REMOVE the second TB port from bridge 0 which makes sense since TB port 2 is connected to an [OWC 4M2 SSD enclosure](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3EX4M2/) containing M2 SSD sticks.  That was previously working, but once I removed TB2 from bridge0 it no longer works.

Do I need to somehow configure TB2 physical interface to be connected do some driver?  How would I do that?  Do I create a service with TB2 and ?? in Network settings?
Or, are TB1 and TB2 really a single physical port that always needs to be bridged?

So the question is, on an iMac with 2 TB ports, can one port be bridged to ethernet, and the second port be bridged to something else, which is NOT ethernet?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome! So you're trying to get networking to the MBA through a TB bridge? Please edit your question to be more specific about which actions you take on each Mac, specifically. It's hard to see the exact troubleshooting sequence. An example: "green 'connected' light" is on _which_ Mac? And: "That was previously working, but once I removed TB2 from bridge0 it no longer works." What no longer works: the net connection, the OWC drive? More detail can define the problem better for us all to help.